# How to put an If Statement inside a Text widget ? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Is it possible to use if statements in a `Text()` widget? I want to display a text only if browns, blacks and whites are true, and I want to display another text only if yellows, blacks and whites are true. Both have the same text style.

**First text:**

```
'Proporção: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos'
```

**Second text:**

```
'Proporção: $yellows dourados : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates'
```

**My code (only with first text yet):**

```
children: [
            Text(
              //add if statements here ?
              'Proporção: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos', 
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'courier',
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  height: 2.5,
                  letterSpacing: 0.7),
            ),],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add tenary operator as like if statement.

```
children: [
            Text(
              //add if statements here ?
              (browns == true && blacks == true && whites == true)
                 ? 'Proporção: $browns agutis : $blacks pretos : $whites albinos'
                 :  (reds == true && yellows == true && blacks == true)?'Proporção: $yellows dourados : $blacks pretos : $browns chocolates': '',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'courier',
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  height: 2.5,
                  letterSpacing: 0.7),
            ),],
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add one more condition, like `(reds == true && blacks == true && yellows == true)` ? Could you edit your answer to fit that case as well?

Comment: @bilbo_bo edited

Comment: I meant like this: what if there are three conditions? (How could I put three if statements there)? Not just one if and one else. I needed to put more than just one if statement, but I'm in trouble with the syntax for that.

Comment: @bilbo_bo as you see there is the 2 condition I put in the answer. ```(condition)?conditionIstrue:(secondCondition)?secondConditionisTrue : (thirdCondition)?thirdConditionIsTrue:thirdConditionIsFalse;```